# Zend Framework table Relationships

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have a table with over 4 million rows, I want to split this table in more tables, i.e one table with 50k rows.
I also need to perform a search on these tables, whats the best way to do it? with JOIN, or? do you have some better ideas?

Best Regards,

QUERY

```
            $do = $this->select()
              ->where('branche LIKE ?',''.mysql_escape_string($branche).'%')
              ->order('premium DESC');
```

Zend_Paginator

```
        $d = $firmen->doSearch($finalType,$theKeyword,$thePLZ,$theBranche,false,false,false,$theOrder);

    $paginator = new Zend_Paginator(

    new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($d)
    );      

    if ($d !== false) {
        //$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($d);
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(5)
                  ->setPageRange(10)
                  ->setCurrentPageNumber($pag);

        $this->view->data = $paginator;
```

Comment: I don't think that would be solution. 4million rows is same 4M rows and in 4 tables :D can you show your shema?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into mysql table partitioning. Assuming you have a good key to split on, with the correct indexes you can get alot of speed gain from doing that. You don't want to manually do it and use join, as that won't work.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html